# unittesting a function in different file in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to test an **add** function that excites in **calc.py**

```
import unittest
import calc
class TestCalc(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_add(self):
        result = calc.add(10,5)
        self.assertEqual(result,15)
```

My question is what does self means in this example

I know that self is an instance of a class.But, can you give me an example of what the value of self would be in my example.

Comment: Is this not covered in the unittest documentation?

Answer (score 1):

`self` is a reference to the instance of `TestCalc` that is instantiated by the test runner from unittest when you run your tests.

More generally, when an object is instantiated and one of its methods is called (such as `test_add()`, called by unittest's test runner in your case), `self` is used to refer to the instance the method is called on, allowing access to its other properties and methods (such as `assertEqual()`, inherited from `unittest.TestCase`, in your case).

Comment: You said (the instance the method is called on) It means that ***self*** refers to ***unites.TestCase*** in my example right? Thank you

Comment: No, it refers to an instance of your class TestCalc, which is a subclass of unittest.TestCase. I think you need object-oriented programming lessons.